# Pulling Instagram data into Google Big Query

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-bigquery, powerbi

I am new to development, so I am sorry if this is a really basic question. I am trying to access some of the data available from instagram's API as documented here. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/insights.

I would like some kind of data repository to pull the data into, so I am looking at Google Big Query to see if I can pull in the data. (The ultimate place will be PowerBi so I can publish online)

Looking at the Facebook request code - is it possible to put this into Google Big query to return the data?

I am replacing the 'instagram-business-user-id' with an ID I have generated already - but it feels like perhaps it needs more markup to let Big Query know what language it is in.

Any help would be  much appreciated.

```html
GET graph.facebook.com/{instagram-business-user-id}/insights
    ?metric=impressions,reach,profile_views
    &period=day
```

Answer (score 4):

> Looking at the Facebook request code - is it possible to put this into Google Big query to return the data?

Yes it's absolutely possible using `bigQuery` API or `bigQuery` CLI

You can use this Psuedo workflow as an example  (using `BigQuery` API):

1. Create a table in `bigQuery` with the desired schema for this you also have 2 options:

   - Save the result in 1 column with the full JSON, This means to the select you need you use [JSON_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) to fetch specific data
   - Process the JSON in your code and save it in specific columns to simplify the select statement
2. Call instagram's [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/insights)
3. Call `bigQuery` API or `bigQuery` CLI to **insert** the data, [This link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) provides one option how to do this
4. Call `bigQuery` API or `bigQuery` CLI to **fetch** the data, [This link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get) provides one option how to do this